# Problems filtering primefaces p:selectManyMenu

Tags: primefaces

I'm using PF 10 and I have some issues with my selectManyMenu. First of all this is my xhtml

```html
<p:selectManyMenu id="abfSelector" value="#{dashboardHandler.selectedAbfragen}"
          var="a" showCheckbox="true" styleClass="manymenu-advanced"
          filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" >
  <f:selectItems value="#{dashboardHandler.abfragen}" var="abfrage" itemLabel="#{abfrage.pk}" itemValue="#{abfrage}"/>
  <p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{a.refSystem.displayName()}"/>
  </p:column>

  <p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{a.name}"/>
  </p:column>  
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

abfragen is a List where Abfrage is as follows:

```java
public class Abfrage implements Serializable, Comparable<Abfrage>{

    @Id 
    @Column(name = "ABF_NR")
    private String pk;
    @Column(name = "ABF_NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "ABF_TQL")
    private String tql;
    @Column(name = "ABF_ZYKLUS")
    private AbfrageZyklus zyklus;
    @Column(name = "ABF_ART")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RequestResolutions typ;
    @Column(name = "ABF_SYSTEM")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ReferenceSystem refSystem;
    @Column(name = "ABF_FUNCTION")
    private String function;
    @Column(name = "ABF_SQL")
    @Lob
    private String sql;
    @Transient
    private boolean notPersisted = true;


    public Abfrage() {  }

    public Abfrage(String pk, String name, String tql, Integer zyklus, String typ, String ref, String function, String sql) {
        this.pk = pk;
        this.name = name;
        this.tql = tql;
        this.zyklus = computeZyklus(zyklus);
        this.setFunction(function);
        this.setSql(sql);
        if(typ != null && !typ.equals("") ) {
            this.typ = RequestResolutions.valueOf(typ);
        }
        if(ref != null && !ref.equals("")) {
            this.refSystem = ReferenceSystem.valueOf(ref);
        }
        this.notPersisted = false;
    }

    private AbfrageZyklus computeZyklus(Integer zyklus) {
        for(AbfrageZyklus z : AbfrageZyklus.values()) {
            int zC = z.getCycle();
            if(zC == zyklus) return z;
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Abfrage abfrage = (Abfrage) o;
        return pk == abfrage.pk &&
                Objects.equals(name, abfrage.name) &&
                refSystem == abfrage.refSystem;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(pk, name, refSystem);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return pk;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Abfrage o) {
        return name.compareTo(o.name);
    }
    
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

My first problem is, that my AbfrageConverter is always null, I think because of the issue with the myFaces version, but I can't find which class I have to change. So sselectedAbfragen is a List and Abfrage.toString() gives my the ID so I can use it further.

But here my problem is that I want to filter the menu by values in the first and second column and the customer wants to use regex but the filter only finds matches in the primary-key.

How can I change the element that it is working, like I hope it would work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So I think the filter ONLY works on the `itemLabel` right?  So you can only filter by what is in there correct?  I don't think it looks at the `p:column` values but I could be wrong?

Comment: With `p:autoComplete` you have full control over how searching should work in the backend.

Comment: Hi, could you please post an example how to filter a list using autoComplete? I don't get how to do it.